# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 : referenced from: _YGConfigNew in libyoga.a(Yoga.o)

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, podspec

Xcode Version - 10.0

React-Native - 0.57.8

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "YGConfig::YGConfig(int (*)(YGConfig*, YGNode*, YGLogLevel, char const*, __va_list_tag*))", referenced from:
>         _YGConfigNew in libyoga.a(Yoga.o)

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: No one answer this. Why?